# Ionic trigger click event does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have a modal in my Ionic app and when modal is shown, I want to trigger click event on specific element.

```
Controller
$scope.$on('modal.shown', function() {
      document.getElementById('somemodal').click(); // #1
      $( "#somemodal" ).triggerHandler( "click" );  // #2
});


Index.html
<h1 class="title" id="somemodal" ng-click="start()">info</h1>
```

Both #1 and #2 do not trigger ng-click which triggers *function start* in **another controller**.

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: My suggestion is to not do DOM manipulation in your controller

Comment: @A.Wolff start() function is in another controller for a reason. That is the reason I need to trigger ng-click on open.

Comment: @devqon Thank you for the advice. But what would be the way to trigger ng-click so I can execute function?

Comment: Perhaps use $rootScope.$broadcast and a listener in the other controller. If both controllers are on the same level, this will not work. But in that case you can add the $broadcast to a factory and call it from your first controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both controllers are on the same level, use a factory like:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('yourapp')
        .factory('yourfactory', yourfactory);

    yourfactory.$inject = [$rootScope];

    /* @ngInject */
    function yourfactory($rootScope) {
        var service = {
            start: start
        };
        return service;

        function start() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('dostart', {});
        }
     }
})();
```

Then in Controller 1 (with the modal):

```
$scope.$on('modal.shown', function() {
      yourfactory.start(); // Don't forget to inject yourfactory
});
```

And in Controller 2:

```
$scope.$on('dostart', function(event, args) {
    $scope.start();
});
```

If both controllers are not on the same level, it is also possible to do a direct `$broadcast` or `$emit` from your first controller without a factory, depending on the hierarchy of your controllers

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by doing below.

```
Controller
$scope.$on('modal.shown', function() {
      $rootScope.start();
});

Another Controller
$rootScope.start= function () {
      some code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
<label class="item">
    <div class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="start()">info</div>
</label>
```

In your controller :

```
$scope.start = function() 
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ionic model

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('yourmodelhtml.html', {
      scope: $scope
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.confirm = modal;
    });
```

then call this $scope.confirm to open up on click event.